# мультиплеер в игре (MultipeerConnectivity)

Tags: ios, swift, разработка-игр, button

По туториалу из youtube попытался сделать мультиплеер. Все работает, но только есть одна проблемка. В строчке `let messageDict = ["coins":button.tag]` передаю на 2-е устройство "сообщение" по тэгу, но исчезает любая другая монетка, но не та на которую нажали на 1 устройстве. Как сделать, чтобы исчезала та монета на 2-м устройстве, на которую нажили на 1-м устройстве? Вот код.

```
@IBAction func coinsHidden(button: UIButton) {
    button.hidden = true
    button.tag = 1
    coins = coins.filter({ !$0.hidden })
            let messageDict = ["coins":button.tag] // вот это строчка ключевая
    do {
        let messageData = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(messageDict, options:
NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        let error:NSError?
        try! appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.sendData(messageData, toPeers: appDelegate.mpcHandler.session.connectedPeers, withMode:
MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable)
        }
}

//multiplayer func
handleReceivedDataWithNotification(notification:NSNotification){
let userInfo = notification.userInfo! as Dictionary
let receivedData:NSData = userInfo["data"] as! NSData    
do {
    let message = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(receivedData, options:
NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSDictionary
    let senderPeerId:MCPeerID = userInfo["peerID"] as! MCPeerID
    let senderDisplayName = senderPeerId.displayName

    if message.objectForKey("string")?.isEqualToString("New Game") == true{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Coin", message: "\(senderDisplayName) has started a new Game", preferredStyle:
UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        let field:Int? = message.objectForKey("coins")?.integerValue
            coins[field!].hidden = true
            coins = coins.filter({ !$0.hidden })
    }
} }
```

Comment: Можете показать ссылку на туториал?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JwqsbsyN3LA